# How to remove a shader (or material) from a particle system in Unity?

Tags: unity, shaders, particles

I bought a Unity asset that has a particle system that displays many small cubes flying around. Then, the creator of this particle system add their own shader (or material) at the end of the particle systems to set the colors of these cubes.

How do I remove this shader (or material) from the particle system ?

---

Here is a picture of a shader (or material) added to a particle system:

[image]

Comment: I what for do you have that particle system? As a compiled asset, in a finished game, as source in your own game?

Comment: @Zibelas, This particle system is part of a Unity asset, which I bought from the Unity asset store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfold the "Renderer" sub-component at the bottom of the list.

Shader materials are used in rendering, so this is where you'll find material settings for the particle system.

Colour modulation can also be accomplished by the Star Color parameter in the top section of the particle system inspector, and Color Over Lifetime sub-component.